# Scrolling Cell Issue at cellForItemAt in UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

EDIT: 
Issue solved. I follow a Youtube tutorial about how to build Youtube from LBTA.

My homeController contains 4 cells which can be scrolled horizontally. each cell (also UICollectionViewCell) has different fetch methods to load data from Firebase.

I have the following code for scrolling:

// in my setupCollectionView

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    }
```

I also have:

```
override func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let index = Int(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / view.frame.width)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
    menuBar.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
    setTitleForIndex(index: index)

}
```

I have a menu bar attached to the collectionView, the menu bar works fine. But the UICollectionViewCell does not.

When I test it by scrolling left and right, the index numbers are all over the place. For example, when I scroll to the first cell, it shows 2, or 3, or sometimes doesn't show anything. When I try to scroll left at the first cell, I still see the cell number changes.

I would like to ask what the appropriate methods are in identifying the cells in my case? Please provide some example codes. Thanks. The image below shows my current state.

Comment: Please provide the code of how you are swiping the cells as well as the delegate callback. Is the swipe gesture in the customCells or is it from the collectionView?

Comment: I don't have swipe gesture. I use scrollDirection = .horizontal. please see the edited code.

Comment: I don't see your edits. Also, you shouldn't say _swiped horizontally_ when you mean scroll horizontally.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just updated that to scrolling from swiping

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt need to override the scrollViewWillEndDragging method. For collectionViews, you are reusing the cells. So when you scroll onto a cell that is offscreen, the collectionViewCellForItemAt method will be called. I'm assuming that you only have 1 cell that is shown at a time. So when a new cell is shown, you can just change the title based on the cell being reused.

```
// Note I only used partial code from your method
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: numberViewCellId, for: indexPath) as! ThirdViewCell 
        cell.delegate = self
        setTitleForIndex(index: indexPath.Row)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I just tried. Thanks anyway. Yes, I show one cell at a time. When I use your method, my leftBarItem shows the wrong title on cells. As you can see in the image. It shows Nearby on the third cell.

Comment: Does your print("Feed") print the correct number when you scroll to that cell?

Comment: No It doesn't print the correct number. That's what I am encountering now

Comment: Okay I am confused now. You are using a collectionView with 4 items in it. Are there more than 4 items? From your screenshot you are showing all four items at a time. Where are you only showing one cell at a time?

Comment: It is showing one cell at a time. The menu bar will move to the correct menu item when I scroll left or right. The white area is for fetch the posts from Firebase. The white area is a UICollectionView  (can be scroll vertically) which nested in 1 the 4 UICollectionViewCells. 4 cells are for loading different type of posts from Firebase. You can think of it as Instagram.

Comment: that circle fire earth and location are on a menu bar which is fixed. The area between the MenuBar and the TabBar are cells which can be scrolled horizontally.

Comment: Ah.. Gotcha. Would it be easier to color coordinate each cell to see what exactly is going on?